# $|x-1| \leq r_{\epsilon}\psi(x)+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $\psi(x) = 1 - x +x\log(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Let $\psi\colon \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}, \psi(x) = 1 - x +x\log(x)$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, I must show that there exists some  $r_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that

$$|x-1| \leq r_{\epsilon}\psi(x)+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$$

From the definition of $\psi$, I know that $|x-1|  = |x\log(x) - \psi(x)|$. Moreover, I know that $\psi$ is convex as well as $x \mapsto x\log(x)$ and that if $x \in [0, 1]$, then $x\log(x) \leq \psi(x)$ and if $x > 1$, then $x\log(x) > \psi(x)$.  I think that the conclusion is not difficult, but I am facing some difficulties. Could someone help me?